# Flex builder error

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

My flex builder suddenly stopped highlighting compile time errors.
Its also not giving any code completion suggestion, even after pressing ctrl+Space.
What could be the possible reasons?

Regards,
PK

Comment: Is is specific to a project/code file? And have you tried to clean your project before building it?

Comment: No, its not specific for project. :( I tried cleaning all... no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens sometimes and it seems for no reason. What may have occurred is you may have an error higher up inside your code of which the compiler has not picked up - This can happen, but when it does the clue is the suggestion stops working and any errors proceeding don't get highlighted.

Clean your project,
restart flex,
check to see if you have the same problem on an another project - you probably won't and this'll show you the clue you have an error in your code.

Be aware the error may not be in that file - it could be in an ajoining mxml file or superclass.